# Pivotal Cloud Foundry version string empty error

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

I am trying to deploy a webapp (manifest.yml file) to enterprise edition of pivotal cloud foundry, when I use the command " cf login " it throws me an error saying

"FAILED
Version string empty"

I've tried entering my api endpoint and tried with using the command -- skip-ssl-validation but that didn't work either, can you guys please help me out where I am going wrong ??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This may help: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/issues/1027

Comment: @mohi Can you check the command cf -v?

Answer (score 0):

There are few links that would be very easy for you to get enabled to `Cloudfoundry` as such

[Getting Started with CF CLI](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/cf-cli/getting-started.html)

[Options available for `cf login` command](https://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/cf/login.html)

[How to Push an App in CF](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/deploy-app.html)

[Options available for `cf push` command](https://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/cf/push.html)